# Prevent to restart activity in xamrin android?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have an MP3 Player in portrait mood? i want to change orientation of playlist activity consist of 2 layouts one is lists of songs when i play any song then we can show that detail on other layout but both in same activity?when i try to do landscape my activity restart and again do all the process from initials and song which are playing also stop again play song from initial ;

also try

```
<activity android:name=".PlaylistActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

and Use `OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)`

but no change problem again existing any solution?

Comment: Your activity has to reinitialise in order to refresh the layout. I suggest you start and stop your player from a service, this way it will not be bounded to the activity.

Comment: Thanks hed shafran